# Apache Zeppelin Web UI keeps on booting (using Docker)

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin

[image: I'm getting this error in the console]

I tried using localhost:8080 & 127.0.0.1:8080
But its not working
I am unable to load the Zeppelin Dashboard.

Comment: You will need to provide some more details of your problem. Obviously you expect Zeppelin to be running locally, but what have you do to make that happen and what have you done to confirm that is is actually running locally?

Comment: I have used the cmd commands for running the process. 
docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.10.0

Comment: By clearing the cached data on the browser, I got it running.